# Sending data to the same page using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**JQuery**

```
$('.Genre_box').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'index.php',
        method:'GET',
        data:{'id':(event.target.id).substr(9)},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('.Genre_box').css('display','none');
            $('#content').css('display','block');
        }
    });
});
```

**Php**

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) echo $_GET['id'];
```

**Html**

```
 <div id="content" style="height:26em; width:67em; position:absolute; left:5em; border:1px black solid; z-index:1; display:none;">
                    <div style="height:100%; width:30%; background-color:green; float:left;">
                        <img src="./_database/genre/<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>.jpg" style="height:100%; width:100%;" alter="genre pic"/>
                    </div>
                    <div style="height:100%; width:70%; background-color:green; float:left;">
                        <div style="height:70%; width:100%; background-color:gray; float:left;">
                            <blockquote style="font-size:2em;"><?php
                                $sql="select descr from genre where id='".$_GET['id']."';";
                                echo $sql;
                                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                                //echo $result;
                                if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                {
                                    echo $row[0];
                                }
                             ?></blockquote>
                        </div>
                        <div style="height:30%; width:100%; background-color:gray; float:left;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Can you guys tell me, where is the problem? I'm not having any output for this. By output, I mean `$_GET['id']` is not being defined. Thanks in the adnvace.

Comment: Should be `type: 'GET'` not `method:'GET'`. If this doesn't help, let's see your html for this page.

Comment: Probably a typo, but missing `'` on the php page: `$_GET['id];`

Comment: Also a typo probably, missing `]` on `$_GET['id')`

Comment: Have you seen what `(event.target.id).substr(9)` actually produces by way of `console.log((event.target.id).substr(9));`? Maybe it's not what you expect?

Comment: @Rasclatt edited the questions. See, if you can understand what's the problem. Becasue it;s going all over my mind.

Comment: Side note, don't do this `$sql="select descr from genre where id='".$_GET['id']."';";`, it's an sql injection exploit waiting to happen.

Comment: @Rasclatt  (event.target.id)substr(9) works fine. I checked that.

Comment: Did you try changing to `type: 'GET'`?

Comment: @Rasclatt yeah. Didn't do the trick

Comment: Does the php page give you an actual error?

Comment: @Rasclatt yes. it says " undefined variable id".

Comment: If you do `print_r($_GET);` or `print_r($_REQUEST);` on the php page, what comes through?

Comment: Also where is the element that has the class `Genre_box`? That doesn't appear in your html snippet

Comment: @Rasclatt an empty array.